# elastic search: get exact match term results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elastic search index with documents having a field "backend_name" like:- google, goolge_staging, google_stg1 etc.

I want only those documents that have "backend_name" = google

I am trying with the term query like this:

```
{ "query": { "term": { "backend_name": "google" } } }
```

But it returns me document having "backend_name" as goolge_staging, google_stg1 too. I want just document with "backend_name" = google.

One way to resolve it is to have goolge_staging, google_stg1 etc. in must not list but I want some better way. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is provably because of the mapping you are using.

Take a look at the Elasticsearch documentation of [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)

Try changing the mapping type to keyword so it matches only if it is an exact match.